# PosgtreSQL - Change multiple fields collation in one query

Tags: postgresql, collation

I have small database with few text fields with `"default"` collation. I don't want to recreate database. What is the query to alter all problematic fields at once?

To change the single one I can use

```
ALTER TABLE a_table_name ALTER a_column_name TYPE text COLLATE a_collate;
```

Comment: You can loop over the columns in a DO block, for example, constructing and executing a dynamic query.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a single SQL command that will do that for you.  You can write a loop in a different language, using the results from

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema IN ('your_schemas')
    AND data_type = 'text'
    AND collation_name IS NULL;
```

or similar.